# How to manipulate multiple csv files with raw data starting from different row for each file?

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to format multiplecsv files, some of them have summaries before the raw data. Raw data can start at any row, but if “colname” is find at any row then raw data start there. I am using the Standard Libary csv module to read files and check if “colname” exist and extract the data from there. With the code below, print(data) always gives me data from the first row of the file. But I want to pull the data starting from where “colname” is found. If “colname” is not found I don’t want to read the data.

```
Root_dir=r”folder1”
for fname in os.listdir(root_dir):
        file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, fname)
        if fname.endswith(('.csv')):
            n = 0
            with open(file_path,'rU') as fp:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(fp)
            while True:
                for line in csv_reader:
                    if line == " colname": continue
                    n = n + 1
                    data=line
                    print(data)
```

Comment: `print(line)` does not appear anywhere in this code.

Comment: I meant print(data)

Answer (score 0):

Your code's logic reads *only skip lines that aren't exactly " colname"*, which has 2 problems:

1. You want to skip lines until AFTER you have seen "colname"; you could use a boolean variable to distinguish between these two situations
2. Not clear if your test for *colname* is correct; for example, if there isn't exactly one leading space, or the line has a trailing end-of-line character, would trip it up.